# How can I prevent certain websites from appearing in my Google search results?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-search

I'm looking for a method to stop a given list of websites from appearing in my Google search results. Any chance I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For Android phones, You have to just click on the options button at the top right corner of the website you want to block and then select not interested in stories from xyz.com. Google will now stop showing anything from that website to you.
If you are using the Chrome Browser on PC, then you are lucky. Because, Chrome has an official extension called Personal Blocklist just for this. You can download and install it from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef?hl=en).

Comment: Umm, we need a solution for Android. Chrome extensions are good but Chrome for Android still doesn't support them.

Comment: Yea. But I think you can block a particular website in Android from your Google Now feed and Google news website. Not sure about the search results though.

Comment: That may be true. Could you please provide details on how to do that with Google Now Feed? That may very well help others too.

Comment: Yea sure. You have to just click on the options button at the top right corner of the website you want to block and then select not interested in stories from xyz.com. Google will now stop showing anything from that website to you.

Comment: @RajaSekar Please edit your answer and put your previous comment as answer if you feel it answers the question. The original answer is for Chrome for PCs, and I don't think it's relevant here :)